# Does DOMParser evaluate inline js or styles?

Tags: javascript, domparser

I'm writing js application, and i have to parse html code came from unreliable source.

Is it safe to do this with `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlHere, "text/html")`? Will `DOMParser` evaluate inline code, load external image or something like this?

Comment: Did you try it? I wouldn't think so, what will it apply the script to? There isn't a browser model attached to the DOM you created.

Comment: I've tried and script was not executed. But I can't simply stop here. Maybe there is some hidden method to do it. I'm trying to find answers is spec to be shure, but found nothing yet :-(